# mahout Recommende Evaluator - test part of data

Tags: java, mahout, recommendation-engine

How can I test my recommender on mahout with only part of data, lets say:

```
user_id, item_id, feature
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 3, 1
2, 1, 1
2, 2, 0
```

And I want to get the precision by testing only the records with feature = 1.

I'm using `GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator` -

```
        RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator evaluator =
       new GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator();
        IRStatistics stats = evaluator.evaluate(
       recommenderBuilder, modelBuilder, model, null, 10,
         GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator.CHOOSE_THRESHOLD,
       1.0);
        System.out.println(stats.getPrecision())
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a an automated way to do this, but in case you want to do it manually

To calculate the precision you need to calculate TP true positives and FP false positives.

That is TP true positives is the correct answers ( feature =1  )

false positives is the wrong answers your recommender retrieved ( based on my understanding is the feature = 0)

And to calculate the precision you calculate P = TP / (TP + FP) ;
This is how you can calculate Precision manually

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your data into test and training and calculate the Average Absolute Difference, refer to RecommenderEvaluator class in Mahout.

Also I have answered your question to obtain precision and recall values in another thread. However I do not believe Precision and recall value would be strong indices for performance.